# Sending data from google drive to SMS

Tags: sms, arduino-uno

i manage to send my temperature sensor data to Google Drive by using Arduino. I am currently stuck in sending message from arduino when my sensor hits a predefined value. I am able to send SMS from Google Drive by using Twilio and some codes to the script editor. By any chance, am i able to connect my Google Drive back to my arduino as i am using 2 different spreadsheets (one for the sensor data, and the other for SMS)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any code which you have tried is not working?  Can you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: Hi @Sid, I used an example on [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVBqUeksR1I&spfreload=10) and it perfectly works for me to send temp data from my arduino to google drive's spreadsheet (lets call it Doc A). I also used an example from [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html) to send SMS from google spreadsheet (Doc B) and it also worked.

Comment: -continue- My problem currently is, I want to link Doc A and Doc B in such a way that if temp data hits a certain value in Doc A, I want it to send to Doc B so it is able to send SMS to my phone automatically.